# Is it possible to look at received queue messages with the Tibco queue client?

Tags: java, queue, jms, tibco, inspect

We're using a Tibco client implementation of the JMS API. We have a `MessageListener` with an `onMessage()` implementation.

Is there a way with the Tibco client to inspect past (received) messages in the queue? (I realise this totally ignores the logical concept of a queue - I wondered if the queue implementation provided this workaround.)

Comment: Just to clarify - messages that have been received and acknowledged already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Not for "past" messages.

Messages acknowledged by the receiver are removed from the queue - as their "function" is already done.

You could have a Listener configured to persist your messages in some DB or file - but for future messages.

Answer (score 0):

A client uses a QueueBrowser object to look at messages on a queue without removing them.

Comment: So you're saying there isn't a way to do this once they're 'removed'.

Comment: Could please explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'm trying to look at messages from the past that have already been received - as a debugging technique.

Comment: You are trying to debug/monitor the server,right? There is the Chapter 17 for this in the EMS User Guide.

Answer (score 0):

@hawkeye Its not possible to browse messages from the past... At any point of time , you can browse destinations only for the pending messages.

```
There is no way for you browse all the received messages as EMS server usually deletes the message once it has delivered ( acknowledged) for the given delivery mode.
One possible way is to a send copy of the messages to another queue (without any receivers) before actually confirming  the messages.
Also it depends on your acknowledgement mode and logic involved.
```